# Magento Product Rules, adding one product at a time

Tags: php, xml, magento, shopping-cart, magento-rules

I sell two services in my Magento store. I've disabled cart and multi-page checkout. I want to sell only one service at a time. Means I want to accomplish, if customer tries to add both services to cart so the previous service should be removed.

How can I accomplish this? I've been searching this from last 5 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the file

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php
```

there is a method `public function addProduct($product, $request = null);`
you should only add `$this->removeAllItems();` to be the first line in the method, like:

```
public function addProduct(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product, $request = null)
{
    $this->removeAllItems(); // new code
    ....
}
```

of course, it's better idea to be overridden in the local pool.

Comment: Thankyou. This one works for me. Check at my URL usecureme.mythstreet.com or usecure.me